# WCF MVC model for A view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, foreach

Im trying to display data to my view by foreach loop but I have problem to define
@model    Can someone help me please.

This is my Service Method

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryType> GetCatList()
        {
            ShopEntities context = new ShopEntities();

            List<Category> produkty = context.Category.ToList<Category>();

            return changeTypee(produkty);
        }

        private List<CategoryType> changeTypee(List<Category> categorie)
        {
            List<CategoryType> productTypes = new List<CategoryType>(); ;
            CategoryType product = new CategoryType();
            foreach (var c in categorie)
            {
                product.ID = c.ID;
                product.Name = c.Name;
                productTypes.Add(product);
            }

            return productTypes;
        }
```

this is my contract

```
[OperationContract()]
        IEnumerable<CategoryType> GetCatList();
```

and this is my controller method

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

            return View(proxy.GetCatList());
        }
```

Error Message

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Shop.Data.CategoryType>>' because 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Shop.Data.CategoryType>>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Comment: It's described fully [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t51esaeb(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks but i still don't get it in my problem.

Comment: @user2397358: are you able to get the `IEnumerable<CategoryType>` in the controller. Did you try using like this `var types = proxy.GetCatList(); return View(types.ToList())`. Also post the view page where you have defined Model.

Comment: @user2397358: also you have to disable `LazyLoading` and `ProxyCreation` in EF when using WCF. Hope you have these in place already.

Comment: Ok so yes im able to reach IEnumerable<CategoryType> in controller
I tried  
and here is my view

`code
 @model ViewPage<IEnumerable<Shop.Data.CategoryType>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>



@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayForModel( Model => item.name);

}`

Comment: Can you post the `foreach` line from your view. It sounds like this is your problem?

Comment: `code @foreach (var item in Model) { @Html.DisplayForModel( Model => item.name); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you get this error in your view? It sounds like you are doing:

```
@foreach (var item in this) { ... }
```

instead of

```
@foreach (var m in this.Model) { ... }
```

The reason I say that is that the error says that `ViewPage<T>` does not have `GetEnumerator`, which it doesn't - it is not enumerable.

**EDIT**

Actually it is this problem, but not quite as I described. You are using:

```
@model ViewPage<IEnumerable<MVC4WebApp_InternetApp.Controllers.CategoryType>>
```

Therefore your model is of type `ViewModel<T>`, instead you need:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC4WebApp_InternetApp.Controllers.CategoryType>
```

**EDIT 2**

1. You'll also need to use this `@Html.DisplayFor( m => item.Name);` instead of `DisplayForModel`.
2. Your `changeTypee` method is messed up

You need to do `CategoryType product = new CategoryType();` inside your loop, not outside, or you will return a list where every entry has the value of the last entry:

```
// Don't do it here: CategoryType product = new CategoryType();
foreach (var c in categorie)
{
    // do it here
    CategoryType product = new CategoryType();
    product.ID = c.ID;
    product.Name = c.Name;
    productTypes.Add(product);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy now Inteli sense working but still have another error

Cannot convert lambdra expression to tyle object because it is not a delegate type

Comment: See edits. But I haven't explained _why_ as the new error isn't related to your question, it is related to your use of `DisplayForModel` inside `foreach`. You should look for other answers on this, or ask a new question if none exist so as to help future people find that answer separately to your original problem.